# Firebase CORS XMLHttpRequest has been blocked problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

I have looked at almost every StackOverflow problem regarding the CORS issue by Firebase and none of them have seemed to work.

I have some cloud functions on Firebase Functions that upload an image if the user is authenticated. I have two files: `index.js` and `user.js`.

Snippet from `index.js`:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const FBAuth = require("./util/fbAuth");
const app = require("express")();

const cors = require("cors")({origin: true});
app.use(cors);

// FBAuth gets a bearer token from firebase and authenticates
app.post("/user/image", FBAuth, uploadImage);

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Snippet from `user.js`

```
exports.uploadImage = (req, res) => {
  const BusBoy = require('busboy');
  const path = require('path');
  const os = require('os');
  const fs = require('fs');

  const busboy = new BusBoy({ headers: req.headers });

  let imageToBeUploaded = {};

  busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    if (mimetype !== 'image/jpeg' && mimetype !== 'image/png') {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Wrong file type submitted' });
    }

    const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
    imageToBeUploaded = { filepath, mimetype };
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
  });
  busboy.on('finish', () => {
    admin
      .storage()
      .bucket()
      .upload(imageToBeUploaded.filepath, {
        resumable: false,
        metadata: {
          metadata: {
            contentType: imageToBeUploaded.mimetype
          }
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        const imageUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${
          config.storageBucket
        }/o/${imageFileName}?alt=media`;
        return db.doc(`/users/${req.user.handle}`).update({ imageUrl });
      })
      .then(() => {
        return res.json({ message: 'image uploaded successfully' });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'something went wrong' });
      });
  });
  busboy.end(req.rawBody);
};
```

**Frontend** in redux/React hosted by Firebase web app:

```
export const uploadImage = (formData) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_USER });
  axios
    .post("/user/image", formData)
    .then(() => {
      dispatch(getUserData());
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

What I've tried:

I tried using `gsutil cors set cors.json`. The problem is all of my other functions work fine, it's only when I upload an image to google storage it fails.

**The error:**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'cloudfunction/user/image' from origin 'link.firebaseapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is this an issue with google cloud storage/firebase rules/spark plan for firebase?

Comment: Can you run the following command to view the CORS configuration for the bucket and post the output : `gsutil cors get gs://[BUCKET_NAME]

Comment: @marian.vladoi This is what came up: `[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["*"], "origin": ["*"]}]`

Should this be changed to something different, even though I've gotten it to work now?

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html), `origin: true` means the origin must match the `Origin` header. Instead you could allow any origin with `origin: "*"`, or just leave empty since this is the default option:

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Still get the same error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'cloudfunction/user/image' from origin 'link.firebaseapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Answer (score 1):

You may try this (without cors)

```
var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {

    var allowedOrigins = [
      'http://link.firebaseapp.com',
    ];
    var origin = req.headers.origin;
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1) {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    }

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    /* if any specific then : */
    // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, accesstoken, latitude, longitude, source');

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
      res.send(200);
    } else {
      next();
    }
};

app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Answer (score 0):

So after much debugging and reverting to a git commit that didn't have the CORS issue, I thought I'd mention it to anyone who has this issue again.

I did the steps that @ariel said, but that didn't work. Turns out, when I initialize the firebase app in `functions`, I had an error, which I commented out to show:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();
// const serviceAccount = require("../db.json");

// admin.initializeApp({
//   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
//   databaseURL: "https://myurl.firebaseio.com",
// });

const db = admin.firestore();

module.exports = { admin, db };
```

Honestly, I'm not sure why it wasn't working before, and I'm not really sure if this was the fix, but I'm not getting the CORS issue anymore, so for anyone else who gets this issue, reverting back to a commit when it worked and going from there is a good way to start.